# How do I implement parallel VideoTimeline in my android as in the kinemaster app?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, video-processing, timeline

[Parallel VideoTimeline in Kinemaster app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DHsog.png)

How to implement the above using recyclerview or any other technique to do the same ?

I have implemented a single timeline using recyclerview for multiple parallel timeline do I have to used another recycler view in sync ?

Answer (score 1):

You could probably nest recyclerviews in this instance to achieve this effect with minimal additional code.

If you're just asking for implementation details, check [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-create-a-nested-recyclerview-in-android/) out.

Carefully consider if the number of layers is going to be dynamic. If not, it may be better to create multiple instances of one adapter rather than nest them.

Comment: yes exactly. I could then sync each recyclerview to scroll together like this https://github.com/dima6120/RecyclerViewsSyncDemo